# Lectura de dos sensores en c# desde arduino

Tags: c#, arduino

Estoy enviando datos desde arduino a Visual Studio usando C#, estoy enviando los datos de un sensor de proximidad, y ahora también tengo que enviar los datos del sensor de humedad y temperatura, entonces como hacer para diferenciar los datos que corresponden a dicho sensor.

```
using System; using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.ComponentModel; 
using System.Data; 
using System.Drawing; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Threading.Tasks; 
using System.Windows.Forms; 
using System.IO.Ports; 
using datacenter.Properties; 
using System.Threading;

namespace datacenter { 

    public partial class datacenter : Form { 

        string dato; 

        public datacenter() {

            InitializeComponent();
            serialPort1.PortName = "COM5";
            serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
            serialPort1.Open();
            alarmaof.Visible = true;
            serialPort1.DataReceived += serialrecive; 

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            circularProgressBar2.Value = 0;
            circularProgressBar2.Minimum = 0;
            circularProgressBar2.Maximum = 10000; 
        }
        private void serialrecive(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string line = serialPort1.ReadLine();
            this.BeginInvoke(new LineReceivedEvent(lineRecived), line);
        }

        private delegate void LineReceivedEvent(string line);
        public void lineRecived(string line)
        {
       //procedimiento para mostrar los datos 
            circularProgressBar2.Text = line;

      //Procedimiento para calcular la distancia
            if(Convert.ToInt32(line) <1000)
            {
                alarmaof.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                alarmaof.Visible = true;
            }
            // procedimiento para la barra circular 
            Thread.Sleep(5);
            circularProgressBar2.Value = Convert.ToInt32(line);
            circularProgressBar2.Update(); 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrás copiar el código que usas para hacer la lectura del sensor de proximidad?

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. Debes [edit] y mejorar tu pregunta. Agrega en la pregunta qué has intentado, qué errores tienes, etc.

Comment: @GustavoCantero esta bien

Comment: Como quedo tu código después de implementar dicho split es que yo tengo que tomar lectura de 8 sensores de proximidad y me gustaría ver la sintaxis

Answer (score 0):

Desde tu codigo arduino. cuando tu lees un x dato desde un sensor, sabes desde que pin lo esta leyendo, para que tu codigo C# sepa de que sensor es el mensaje, solo antepone un character antes del valor.
ejm:
H,64 (sensor humedad)

Luego en C# separas usando un split

Espero te sirva

Comment: Gracias me sirvió mucho tu comentario de echo lo implemente y si me funciono.